# Make Gnu MP library with minGW: "Nothing to be done for Makefile.in"

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, autotools, gmp

I want to use the GMP (https://gmplib.org/) on Windows, so i downloaded the folder called gmp-6.1.0 and tried to use mingw32-make.exe on it. It printed: "mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." But there is a Makefile.in in the folder. When i tried "mingw32.exe Makefile.in" it printed out "Nothing to be done for Makefile.in".

I really don't know what to do here, since a guy over here: [How to compile makefile using MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772602/how-to-compile-makefile-using-mingw)
said i'd just need to mingw32.exe makefile.in

Comment: As indicated in GMP docs, you should first launch "configure" command to generate the final makefile, that will be named "makefile", so that the "mingw32-make" command will work well.

Comment: Yea well, but how do i do that on windows?

Comment: Ok I figured out that I need MSYS to do that. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install GMP you should:
 1. Install MSYS or Cygwin (with at least Autotools package and make utility)
 2. Run "./configure" command in order to generate the makefile, simply called "makefile"
 3. Run "make" command to build
 4. Run "make install" to install GMP

Answer (score 0):

So if you're using *Vscode* and *Mingw* then you should first make sure that the bin folder of the *Mingw* is included in the environment `path` and it is preferred to change the `mingw32-make.exe` to `make` to ease the task and then create a *makefile* and include this code in it .

```
all:
    gcc -o filename filename.c
    ./filename
```

Then save the *makefile* and open Vscode *Code* terminal and write `make`. Then makefile will get executed.