# Codelite not running C programs

Tags: c, windows-10, mingw, codelite

Everytime I try to build and run a program, including the standard 'Hello world!' nothing happens, I get:

> ==== Program exited with exit code: 0 ====
> Time elapsed: 000:00.000 (MM:SS.MS)
> Press any key to continue...

At the bottom it says:

> 'ming32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable prgram or batch file.

I have Codelite version 16 on Windows 10. I also have MinGW installed to C: and have edited the Environment variables to include C:\MinGW\bin

However, in command prompt `gcc --version` shows me the gcc version in `C:\Users\me>` and not `C:\MinGW`

I don't know if this is relevant or not.

All the other results seem to suggest a compiler not found problem, but this does not seem to be my case. Thanks in advance.

This is what I have installed at the moment. Can I get 'make'from one of the other files?

[The Installed files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gd5b.jpg)

Comment: Make sure both gcc and make is in your PATH and it should work.

Comment: Of the 2 you mentioned I only see `C:\MinGW\bin` in System variables -> Path

Comment: And does that bin folder have both gcc and ming32-make?

Comment: I think you have just entered mingw32-make wrong in codelite

Comment: No, there is no `mingw32-make` in that bin folder. When I used the Installer originally I only selected: mingw32-gcc-g++-bin although there were other bin files. Where can I get it?

Comment: No, see previous reply

Comment: Is there a make.exe? You can rename or copy it. Or you can adjust the Codelite preference.

Comment: There is nothing related to 'make' whatsoever in the `C:\MinGW\bin` folder. Is it supposed to come with the standard `mingw32-gcc-g++-bin` installation?

Comment: @Fari well then that is the error, you don't have make. And yes I'm pretty sure it's part of the mingw32 bundle

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you either don't have `ming32-make.exe` or it can't be found.

Also I notice you still use old MinGW. I would recommend switching to newer MinGW-w64 (which supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit).

The standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ does include `ming32-make.exe`, and since you can just unzip it (no installation needed) you can try it without removing the old MinGW. Just make sure you don't have anything in your `PATH` variable to avoid running programs from the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

`ming32-make.exe` is either not installed or can't be found on your Environment variable `PATH`.

> No, there is no mingw32-make in that bin folder. When I used the Installer originally I only selected: mingw32-gcc-g++-bin although there were other bin files. Where can I get it?

`mingw32-make` is outdated.

See [How to compile makefile using MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772602/how-to-compile-makefile-using-mingw/11775683#11775683)

If you are having problems with mingw, I would recommend using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) or a package manager  like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install).

Just get rid of the previous installation first. Not mandatory but prevents confusion and storage drain due to multiple copies of mingw.

To install MinGw using chocolatey, run cmd as admin and use

```
choco install mingw
```

For `make`

```
choco install make
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was also installing `mingw32-base-bin` from the Installer (see second option in image in the original question).
The installation tutorial I was following did not mention installing this.
I've decided to leave this here as an answer in case someone else runs into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

MSYS is a good option for compilers in recent CodeLite or VS-Code installation. https://www.msys2.org/.

Once you downloaded the compiler using the following steps from the [installer](https://www.msys2.org/#:%7E:text=and%20what%20for.-,Installation,-Download%20the%20installer) but still have the problem with the `make` then follow these steps:

1. Reopen the MSYS2 terminal from your windows if that is previously installed.
2. Run the command `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`
3. You will be asked to select the option from the list. You should select the option which refers to `mingw-w64-x86_64-make`.
4. Once the installation is successfully done, then open CodeLite `settings->Buid Settings` and check your `Make` file location. If that is empty or showing an unknown location then click the three dots at the very right of that box. The browse and navigate to location or where you installed the `make` by pacman. In my case it is `C:/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe`.

[image]

5. Click Apply and Save.
6. Now it might be needed to create a fresh workspace and re-run your code.