CodeLite not running c++ program
I configured CodeLite version 17.10 on Windows and the compiler I'm using is MinGW-w64 version GCC 14.2.0. I wrote the following code:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

When I try to build it works without any errors but when I run I get the following:
==== Program exited with exit code: 32760 ====
Time elapsed: 000:00.000 (MM:SS.MS)
Press any key to continue...

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and how can I fix this?
Also what does the code 32760 indicate?

See the duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446978/codelite-not-running-c-programs

Normally IDEs return OS exit codes but that one does not seem to match a Windows exit code. Did you look at the folder? Was an executable produced? Were there any .o files produced? Did you try disabling your antivirus?

I think recommending a dupe with no voted or selected answers to be a lateral move at best. I also don't think CodeLite can call itself an IDE if it doesn't do any integrating of the tools for you.

For me, it's a compiler error.  I use both C and C++ with codelite and if I forget to change my compiler when I go from one to the other (hit the wrench in the Project Folder menu to change), I will get that error.  I hope this helps.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
